# java generic ambiguity

Tags: java, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

If there is a generic type `node<E>` with two operations like `setData(E Type)` and `E getData()` and let `s0` be a instance of `node` by `node<? extends Number>` then why don't the compiler allow me to use `s0.setData(Number Type)` at least? I can understand why other types are not allowed but why not allow the `setData` to put in a Number type as we are sure that the type of node will be at least number?

My code looks like this:

```
class Node<E> {
private E data;
// ...
public void setData(E obj) { data = obj; } // (1)
public E getData() { return data; } // (2)
// ...
}
Node<? extends Number> s0 = new Node<Number>();
s0.setData(200); //this is not allowed why?
Node<Number> s0 = new Node<Number>();
s0.setData(100); //But this is allowed!
```

Comment: How are you testing the code?

Comment: Show some code, it's hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the type a `Node<? extends Number>`. What you *assign* to it is irrelevant.

As far as the compiler is concerned it could be any of the following:

- `Node<Integer>`
- `Node<Float>`
- `Node<Double>`
- etc

And it has no way of knowing which type is the *actual* type.

You are trying to pass an (auto-boxed) `Integer`, but the compiler can't know that the *actual* type can accept an `Integer`.

Comment: Why not, have't we told it that it could atleast be a Number or any of its subtype via ? extends Number and is't integer a subtype for Number?

Comment: Why not? Because you could have assigned a `Node<Float>` to the variable `Node<? extends Number> s0`. What do you think will happen if you call the `setData()` method of a `Node<Float>` with an `Integer`?

Comment: With reference to the code I have posted, Why can't I add any subtype? at the same type you can do setData(200) when the type is just Node<Number>

Comment: No!!! The type is NOT `Node<Number>`! The type is `Node<? extends Number>`. You have *assigned* a `Node<Number>`, but the compiler only looks at the *declared* type. It's all explained in my answer - please re-read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have reference `Node<? extends Fruits> s0`. It means that it can point to

```
Node<? extends Fruit> s0 = new Node<Fruit>;
```

but also

```
Node<? extends Fruit> s0 = new Node<Apple>;
```

and

```
Node<? extends Fruit> s0 = new Node<Banana>;
```

How do you think, would it be safe to let it add `Fruit` to Bananas or Apples? Or Banana to Apples? What if Apple and Banana contains methods that Fruit doesn't.

Comment: We know that node can atleast be fruit then why not allow add a subtype of fruit. Why is the add operation not allowed with extend and only with super?
I could always do s0.setFruit(Apple) and get it back using getFruit() where am I violating type safety?

Comment: If Java would allow to add any Fruits via `Node<? extends Fruit> s0`, then it would mean that it would be possible to also add Bananas to Apples. Take a look `Node<? extends Fruit> s1 = new Node<Apple>; s1.add(new Banana());` would be correct, because `Banana extends Fruit`.

Answer (score 0):

In subtance: because a `Node<Integer>` for example, is not a `Node<Double>`. [It is not even a `Node<Number>`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Example:

```
Node<? extends Number> s0 = new Node<Integer> ();
s0.setData(Double.valueOf(2.0d)); //that's not possible...
```

Actually, because we don't know what the generic type of `s0` is, you won't be able to call the `setData` method on anything but `null`...

Comment: But have we not sure that it could atleast be a number, then why not allow to put a number in?

Comment: @VishakhPC In my example, s0 is really about Integer, so there is no reason why the compiler would allow you to add Doubles or BigDecimals in there.